# Disable prettyPhoto specific link by detecting a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, overlay, prettyphoto

Looking into solution of how to completely disable prettyPhoto poup overlay in case the clicked link has a specific class. So far, no matter what it keeps ignoring my if condition.

Here  is the code:

```
    (function(){
            var targetLink = $('.popup');                              

            targetLink.click(function(){

            if($(this).hasClass('mobile')){

            //do my stuff and then          

            } else {

            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                deeplinking:false,
                social_tools:false      
            });

            }

return false;

            });

        })();
```

Any idead would be apreciated.

thak you.

Answer (score 0):

This should stop prettyPhoto being applied to links where the element has a class of mobile.

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:not(.mobile)").prettyPhoto({
    deeplinking:false,
    social_tools:false      
});
```

Comment: unfrotunatly it is stilling showing up if like it detects the rel=prettyphoto before anything else..

Comment: do you have any other solution?